# Can not install package within docker debian:jessie

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am tryint to install git within debian based container

postgres image is based on debian:jessie

dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:9.4


RUN apt-get -qq update

RUN apt-get install git-core
RUN apt-get install osm2pgsql
```

Both git and osm2pgsql can not be located

error

```
E: Unable to locate package git-core
```

What have I missed ?

Comment: obsolete. "The 'git-core' package has been renamed to 'git'" https://packages.debian.org/jessie/git-core

Answer (score 22):

I don't what's causing the 'unable to locate package' error, but your `apt-get` invocations are missing `-y`, which means you're going to get:

```
After this operation, 33.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install git-core' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Otherwise, your Dockerfile worked just fine for me:

```
Step 1 : RUN apt-get -qq update
 ---> Running in 0430a990fa81
 ---> 54f88a02d81e
Removing intermediate container 0430a990fa81
Step 2 : RUN apt-get install git-core
 ---> Running in 0fdad2e3c35b
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates git git-man less libcurl3-gnutls liberror-perl libidn11
  librtmp1 libssh2-1 libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxext6
  libxmuu1 openssh-client patch rsync xauth
Suggested packages:
  gettext-base git-daemon-run git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email
  git-gui gitk gitweb git-arch git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn ssh-askpass
  libpam-ssh keychain monkeysphere ed diffutils-doc openssh-server
Recommended packages:
  ssh-client
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates git git-core git-man less libcurl3-gnutls liberror-perl
  libidn11 librtmp1 libssh2-1 libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6
  libxext6 libxmuu1 openssh-client patch rsync xauth
0 upgraded, 21 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,059 kB of archives.
After this operation, 33.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install git-core' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: failed to build larsks/sodocker:latest
```